# Solve XAB + YZCD = ZEXY

Tags: mathematics, alphametic

Replace each letter with a digit between 1 and 8 to make the equation

$XAB + YZCD = ZEXY$ true. Each letter represents a different digit.

**Bonus question:** How many solutions are there in total?

Comment: Could you clarify if you want numbers between 1 to 8 or 1 to 9? And welcome to Puzzling!!!

Comment: http://www.tkcs-collins.com/truman/alphamet/alpha_solve.shtml here is online solver... i am not sure what is different of this question ehich could be solved easily with an solver?

Answer (score 1):

There could be more, but in base 10, I see 4 solutions:

Solution 1:

> A=1 B=2 C=7 D=3 E=4 X=8 Y=5 Z=6 
>  5673+812=6485

Solution 2:

> A=1 B=3 C=7 D=2 E=4 X=8 Y=5 Z=6
> 5672+813=6485

Solution 3:

> A=7 B=2 C=1 D=3 E=4 X=8 Y=5 Z=6 
> 5612+873=6485

Solution 4:

> A=7 B=3 C=1 D=2 E=4 X=8 Y=5 Z=6 
>  5613+872=6485

Clarification - I had initially posted an answer that had 0 in it, but I hadn't read the rules and so, I have changed my answer.

Comment: But 0 is not allowed (only numbers 1 to 9)....

Comment: @PuzzleMaker 1-8 or 1-9? Sorry, I misread as 0-9..

Answer (score 1):

I've got another one (by which I mean another four):

> $A=5,~B=2,~C=8,~D=4,$
> $E=1,~X=3,~Y=6,~Z=7.$
> $\quad\qquad\begin{align}352\\+\quad6784\\\hline7136\end{align}$
> Solutions come in groups of four,
> because we can switch $A~$↔$~C$
> and $B~$↔$~D$,
> so we could also have $A=8,~C=5$ and/or $B=4,~D=2.$

I believe that [Sid's answer(s)](//puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/46123/19765#46124) and mine are the only possible ones;
i.e., there are eight solutions.